# named functions as object property values in javascript

Tags: javascript

First off, sorry, I'm not sure what to search for on this one or I would have done more research. Recently I'm confronted with code like this

```
{ thinkImClever: function thinkImClever() { } }
```

If you ask me that should be written as

```
{ thinkImClever: function() { } }
```

I was told by the folks who put a lot of this together that the former is helpful for debugging. Is that true, or can I consider it cruft as my intuition tells me?

Comment: That is true. But usually its overvalued.